# Show root of unity summation

Tags: summation, proof-writing, roots-of-unity

I have this math problem

> Let $w$ be a root of unity with $o(w)=n$, with $n > 1$.  Show that $$1
>  + w + w^2 + \cdots + w^{n-1}  = 0$$

I'm not entirely sure how to start this problem. Would I need to use proof by induction? If so, how would I start it? Thanks.

Comment: It is a geometric series. Try summing it.

Comment: What's $w$ times the bit on the left?

Comment: Also, look at the geometry, certainly for even $n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$(1-w)(1 + w + w^2 + \cdots + w^{n-1})=1-w^n$$

and $w\neq 1$ is a root of $1$.

Comment: My answer exactly, you beat me to it. +1 for you :)

Comment: +1 Coincidentally, I was thinking about this and its implications while dosing off last night.  Now that is scary on multiple levels ;-)